# How To Lock Down Windows RT

Tags: windows, user-accounts, automation, windows-store, windows-rt

I have a Windows tablet that is running Windows RT. I would like to "lock down" Windows from a normal user. I would like to remove the charm bar, or disable it. I have an App this is running on the desktop. Every time some brushes the side of the tablet and hits the Windows key (start button), they lose the desktop and go to the start menu. Then they don't know how to navigate back, and this becomes a hassle.

I would like for them not to be able to leave the desktop at all.

On another note I have tried to install the 8.1 preview about 10 times. Once I download the hotfix, and try to install it Windows Store, it doesn't show up in Windows Store

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround to install Windows 8.1 download the ISO, mount it, run `setup.exe` and select `upgrade`.

To [disable the corners in Windows 8 you can use ClassicShell](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-hot-corners-charms-bar-start-screen-thumbnail-app-switch-list-in-windows-8/):

[image]

You can also configure that the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> key does nothing in the Classic shell options.

*// Edit:
Do you use 8 or RT? There is a modified RT version:
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/get-classic-start-menu-disable-start-screen-on-windows-rt-tablets/*

Comment: It is Windows RT. I am going to try this.

Comment: I can't use either of these options. I can't jail break the tablet. And since it is RT I can't install app outside the Windows Store.

Comment: in this case you're out of luck. Wait until MS released the final of 8.1 which also offers options to disable the hot corners http://www.pcworld.com/article/2042933/windows-8-1-will-let-you-disable-hot-corners-and-shut-down-from-the-start-button.html

Answer (score 1):

These things are managed using *policies* in Windows. Try running gpedit.msc. You should find it by simply searching for gpedit.

Be careful, as you might possibly lockout yourself as I don't know how to start a Windows RT tablet in safe mode.

Note that it is possible that they don't have options for locking down the things you wish to lock down, but you would have to look through the options that are available in gpedit.

Note also that within gpedit, you can use filtering. Due to the amount of options, I'd turn on the filter and show only properties that apply to Windows RT.

You would also have to [enable policies for Windows RT](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2012/12/how-to-enable-and-configure-group-policy-settings-in-windows-rt/).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't own a Windows Tablet myself, so I'm not sure if it will work.

Did you try to mount the ISO with software like

- [SkySoft Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) or
- [Daemon-Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/downloads)?

For the corner problem: Maybe a rough way, but killing the explorer task will also disable the corner functions.

Make a batch file with:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
echo Press a key to restart Windows Explorer.
pause>nul
explorer.exe
exit
```

Then start the batch file to disable the corners, and after that go with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the command prompt and press a key to enable the corners again.

Comment: I believe neither of these work in Windows RT.

Comment: This doesn't work in RT, but thank you. This will work in older versions.